# jQuery UI : Resizable Coustom Duoble-Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

copied following code from http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#default

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>#resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
#resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
</script>
<div class="demo">
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

It outputs this.
  [image]

 I want to capture the double click event for each of cursor position so that if

1. Double click by horizontal re-size cursor, i can toggle width of current resizable between original and maximun available width.
2. Double click by vertical re-size cursor, i can toggle height of current resizable between original and maximun available height.
3. Double click by diagonal re-size cursor, i can toggle width and height of current resizable between original and maximun available width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handlers have specific classNames:

```
ui-resizable-se//bottom right
ui-resizable-s//bottom
ui-resizable-e//right
```

You can select them and bind the dblclick:

```
$('.ui-resizable-se').dblclick(function(){alert('clicked bottom right handle');})
```

A pointer to the resizable you'll get inside the function using `$(this).parent()`

Answer (score 2):

Use firebug to find out the elements you ant to attach the event (like: .ui-resizable-e - self explanatory) and use for example:

```
$(".ui-resizable-e").dblclick(myFunctionToResize);
```

Is that what you mean?